# Firebase retrieve date of posted image and calculate how many days between start date and current date

Tags: java, android, firebase, datetime, firebase-realtime-database

So this is my design and the textview of my wanted time is at the bottom left this is where I am viewing my x days and its at Default currently its not calculating the days normally.

[image]

So I am having a problem regarding retrieving the date of a posted image and calculate the x days between the start and current date independently for each post.

So I was trying to get the time stamp difference date in a method tried to call that method to another method to set the days difference between the start and current date in my TextView. I have tried several ways i only get Default result, perhaps I am using this the wrong way?

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Post> mPosts;
    private Post post;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    public PostAdapter(Context context, List<Post> posts){
        mContext = context;
        mPosts = posts;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostAdapter.ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);
        return new PostAdapter.ImageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( final PostAdapter.ImageViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final Post post = mPosts.get(position);



        if(post.getPostimage() != null) {
            Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext()).load(post.getPostimage())
                    .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder))
                    .into(holder.post_image);



        }
        else
        {
            Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext()).load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/araba-92732.appspot.com/o/placeholder.png?alt=media&token=b98a5c60-1ebf-4d14-bad4-b4e707c59d56")
                    .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder))
                    .into(holder.post_image);
        }

        if (post.getCarType() == null
                && post.getPrice() == null
                && post.getModel() == null
                && post.getDistance() == null
                && post.getColor() == null
                && post.getLocation() == null){

            holder.carType2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.price.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.model.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.distance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.color.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tvLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        else {
            holder.carType2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.carType2.setText(post.getCarType());

            holder.price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.price.setText(post.getPrice());

            holder.model.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.model.setText(post.getModel());

            holder.distance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.distance.setText(post.getDistance());

            holder.color.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.color.setText(post.getColor());

            holder.tvLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tvLocation.setText(post.getLocation());
        }

        publisherInfo(holder.image_profile, holder.tvPublisher, post.getPublisher());
        isLiked(post.getPostid(), holder.like);
        isSaved(post.getPostid(), holder.save);
        nrLikes(holder.likes, post.getPostid());

if(firebaseUser != null) {
    holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (holder.like.getTag().equals("like")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid())
                        .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                addNotification(post.getPublisher(), post.getPostid());
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid())
                        .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }
        }
    });

    holder.save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (holder.save.getTag().equals("save")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saves").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                        .child(post.getPostid()).setValue(true);
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saves").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                        .child(post.getPostid()).removeValue();
            }
        }
    });
}
        holder.image_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", post.getPublisher());
                editor.apply();

                ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            }
        });


            holder.post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString("postid", post.getPostid());
                    editor.apply();

                    ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            new PostDetailFragment()).commit();
                }
            });


        holder.likes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FollowersActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", post.getPostid());
                intent.putExtra("title", "likes");
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                            case R.id.edit:
                                editPost(post.getPostid());
                                return true;
                            case R.id.delete:
                                final String id = post.getPostid();
                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts")
                                        .child(post.getPostid()).removeValue()
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                    deleteNotifications(id, firebaseUser.getUid());
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                return true;
                            case R.id.report:
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Reported clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;
                            default:
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.post_menu);
                if (!post.getPublisher().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                    popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.edit).setVisible(false);
                    popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.delete).setVisible(false);
                }
                else if (post.getPublisher().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                    popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.report).setVisible(false);
                }

                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPosts.size();
    }

    class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView image_profile, post_image, like, save, more;
        TextView carType2, likes, carType, price, model, distance, color, tvLocation, tvPublisher, iTP;

        ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
            carType2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.carType2);
            post_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
            save = itemView.findViewById(R.id.save);
            likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
            carType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.carType);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            model = itemView.findViewById(R.id.model);
            distance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            color = itemView.findViewById(R.id.color);
            tvLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
            tvPublisher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPublisher);
            iTP = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_time_posted);

            more = itemView.findViewById(R.id.more);
            }

        private void setupWidgets(){
            String timestampDiff = getTimestampDifference();
            if(!timestampDiff.equals("0")){
                iTP.setText(timestampDiff + " DAYS AGO");
            }else{
                iTP.setText("TODAY");
            }

        }

        private String getTimestampDifference(){

            String difference = "";
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.GERMAN);
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("German"));//google 'android list of timezones'
            Date today = c.getTime();
            sdf.format(today);
            Date timestamp;
                final String photoTimestamp = post.getPostimage();

                try {
                    timestamp = sdf.parse(photoTimestamp);
                    difference = String.valueOf(Math.round(((today.getTime() - timestamp.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24)));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    difference = "0";
                }

            return difference;
        }
    }
```

This is my Home Fragment that contain the RV of the posts

```
package com.capstone.araba.Fragments;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.capstone.araba.Adapter.PostAdapter;
import com.capstone.araba.Model.Post;
import com.capstone.araba.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
{

    private PostAdapter postAdapter;
    private List<Post> postList;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;


    private List<String> followingList;

    private ProgressBar progress_circular;
    private EditText search_bar, search_bar2;
    private TextView iTP;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home_fragment, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        search_bar = view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        search_bar2 = view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar2);
        postList = new ArrayList<>();
        postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), postList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);


        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

        progress_circular = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular);

        search_bar.clearFocus();
        search_bar2.clearFocus();

        checkFollowing();
        readPostsSearch();

        search_bar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                searchPosts(charSequence.toString(),"carType");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        search_bar2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                searchPosts(charSequence.toString(),"location");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
        return view;
    }



    private void searchPosts(String s, String type){

            final Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild(type)
                    .startAt(s.toUpperCase())
                    .endAt(s.toLowerCase() + "\uf8ff");

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                postList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    postList.add(post);
                }

                postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }



    private void readPostsSearch() {

        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (search_bar.getText().toString().equals("") || search_bar2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    postList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                        progress_circular.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        postList.add(post);

                    }

                    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void checkFollowing(){
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        assert firebaseUser != null;
        followingList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(firebaseUser != null) {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Follow")
                    .child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid())
                    .child("following");


            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    followingList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        followingList.add(snapshot.getKey());
                    }

                    readPosts();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void readPosts(){
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");


            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    postList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);

//                    for (String id : followingList){
//                        if (post.getPublisher().equals(id)){
                        postList.add(post);
                        progress_circular.setVisibility(View.GONE);

//                        }
//                    }
                    }

                    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    progress_circular.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: The log says NullPointerException calling getPostimage()
Which I find in your onBindViewHolder method. Which says that the Post at that position in your list mPost is Null.
But your code snippets do not provide Informations about how you fill your List mPost. 
If you just dont want a NPE just add a wrapper if (post != null){..}
If you want to know why mPost.get(position) is null you have to provide code about mPost.

Comment: I have shortened my code so I could only point out the problem but i guess its better to post related codes as well please let me update my information

Comment: @Traendy I have updated my codes with mPost.position thanks for pointing this out